# hyperlink in firefox to windows share

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, hyperlink, share, smb

I am having trouble creating a hyperlink to a windows share, that works correctly in firefox and IE9.

The original line was this:

```
<a href="\\10.1.3.33\sharename\filename.txt" target="_new">Link</a>
```

This works correctly in IE9, andopens the file as you would expect. However, this does not seem to work in firefox, as it just appends the above to the root directory, so it ends up looking in:

/\10.1.3.33/sharename/filename

I have tried as someone suggested and appending file:// to the pathname, but this does not seem to load anything in firefox, but does work in IE.

Can anyone advise on what I should be using the get a link to a network share working in all browsers?

Many thanks, Eds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Believe this is a security feature in Firefox, Chrome and Safari. Don't think there is a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue solved:

IE & Chrome:

```
href="\\server\whatever\"
```

Firefox:

```
href="file://///server\whatever\"
```

However, if your web is considered as "internet zone", you will NOT be able to open it in none of them.